# Template application default parameter

Tags: java, templates, stringtemplate-4

I'll try to make my problem seem simple, hoping that the solution will be.

Let's state that we have two templates as following :

```
html(data,value,charts) ::= <<
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    [...]
        var $data$ = $value$;
        $charts$
    [...]
    </html>
>>

chart(chartname,data,categoryname,graphs) ::= <<
    var $chartname$;
    $chartname$.dataProvider = $data$;
    [...]
>>
```

In Java, I have to do something like:

```
ST myPage = group.getInstanceOf("html");
ST chart1 = group.getInstanceOf("chart");
ST chart2 = group.getInstanceOf("chart");
myPage.add("data", xxx );
chart1.add("data", xxx );
chart2.add("data", xxx );
```

BUT, "data" is the same for all (code duplication!), so I would like to apply the "chart" template on data in my "html" template with something like :

```
html(data,value,charts) ::= <<
    [...]
        var $data$ = $value$;
        $charts(data)$
    [...]
>>
```

Which is not possible, because the "chart" template as more parameter than just "data".

My question is :
How to call the "chart" template, using "html"."data" for "chart"."data" but by keeping the usual way to set parameter at runtime with .add(String, Object) ..?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

One option is to remove the `data` parameter from the `chart` template. Doing so would allow cause the reference to `data` within `chart` to look up the attribute in the calling context (e.g. the `html` template). However, this would mean the following as well:

1. You could not explicitly set the `data` argument for an instance of a `chart` template (the last 2 lines in your Java code would throw an exception).
2. The `chart` template could not be rendered independently. If you needed to render a `chart` template without an `html` template, you'd need to define a new template like `standaloneChart(data, chart)` that would allow you to render the `chart` template in a context that defines `data`.

Comment: As I have an composition relation between my chart and my html page, I can deal with those two consequences.
Can you please develop your advice about "look up the attribute in the calling context" ? How could I do ?
(Thank you by the way )